# Taking a random word from a text and then returning all the words that come 1 index after it? (Python)

Tags: python

```
import random

book = open("emma.txt").read()
book2 = book[0:]

words = book2.split()
prefix = random.choice(words)
print(prefix)

with open("emma.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for word in line.split():
            if prefix in word:
                #Return the next word in line
```

I'm essentially taking a random word from a text and then returning all the words that come 1 after it in the entire text.
For the last line of code, I actually want to print the word that comes directly after the prefix word, but I don't know how to without throwing it out of range.

Comment: give more example if you have a text **I dont like apples on friday** if your word is **like**  you want to return **on friday** is it?

Comment: I would just want to return "apples"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `enumerate` here. I have modified the `for` loop line to do that. `enumerate` runs a counter that allows you to know the current position of the `for` loop.

```
import random

book = open("emma.txt").read()
book2 = book[0:]
words = book2.split()
prefix = random.choice(words)
print(prefix)

with open("emma.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        for i, word in enumerate(line.split()[::-1]):
            if prefix in word:
                print(line.split()[i+1])
```

Note that I am not traversing through all the words but only up to the second last word.

Comment: There are instances that this will throw `IndexError: list index out of range` error

Comment: @CodeRed, you mean instances where `line.split()` returns only one element?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about lines with only one word. This could be a rare situation for the OP.

Comment: @CodeRed In that case, there would be no next word to pick. Also, if the randomly chosen word is the last one, there'll index out of bounds error. But I think the question was more about getting the word coming after a chosen word.